# Is there a way that gives shortest path using Floyd-Warshall's algorithm where negative weight cycle exists whereas overlapped edges are not allowed?

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, graph

We know that the result of Floyd-Warshall's algorithm is invalid if a negative weight cycle appears in the graph, that is because to travel multiple times on the negative weight cycle makes the weight sum arbitrarily small. However if we specify that no duplicated edge are allowed to be travelled on then the weight sum is correct by sense. I want to know a way that produces the least weight sum in such condition. Some modifications of the algorithm have been tried (Including to skip the loop when a weight sum from some vertex to itself is minus) but the predecessor matrix was still weird and the weight sum matrix was totally useless (By chance I knew that an exponentially increasing value of it would inevitably occur, see [link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220110597_The_Floyd-Warshall_algorithm_on_graphs_with_negative_cycles)).

Comment: You might want to change your algorithm, eg, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm.

Comment: @NeilEdelman No, I will not use that algorithm because it cannot solve my problem as well.  I mean I just want an variant of the floyd-warshall's algorithm in which  no duplicate edges allowed to be travelled on.

Answer (score 1):

An efficient solution to that problem would imply P=NP, so there almost certainly isn't such a solution.

With a polynomial-time solution to your problem, you could solve the [longest trail problem](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20682/is-the-longest-trail-problem-easier-than-the-longest-path-problem) by setting all edge weights to -1 and asking for the shortest path between two nodes.

As proven by Marzio De Biasi in the linked post, a solution to the longest trail problem can be used to solve the Hamiltonian cycle problem on grid graphs of max degree 3, by connecting two new nodes to the top-left node and asking for the longest trail.

The Hamiltonian cycle problem is still NP-complete when restricted to grid graphs of max degree 3, as proven in Christos H Papadimitriou, Umesh V Vazirani, On two geometric problems related to the travelling salesman problem, Journal of Algorithms, Volume 5, Issue 2, June 1984, Pages 231-246, ISSN 0196-6774.

Thus, your problem is NP-hard.